# Importing Certificates - Access denied (while run as administrator)

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I'm working on automating the add of a certificate I created from `Cert:\CurrentUser\My` to `Cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher` so that I can use the AllSigned ExecutionPolicy.  When I use the `Import-PfxCertificate` cmdlet (after exporting, obviously), I'm getting `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

The weird thing about all of this, I can go into the certificates MMC and import the certificate myself, but when trying to run it through PowerShell (as administrator), it's giving me the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I was able to import the cert to the LocalMachine, but not CurrentUser.

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath 'Path\Cert.pfx' -Password (Get-Credential).Password -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath 'Path\Cert.pfx' -Password (Get-Credential).Password -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher
```